# Does qualified immunity still apply if an officer resigns?

Tags: united-states

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnmqsnugGw0) showing some details about the case.

A business owner is falsely arrested at his place of business. The business owner was unable to obtain the name of all the officers involved. The business owner then sees the officer that was involved with his false arrest during an incident near his business.

The department conducts an internal investigation and admitted it was a false arrest. The officer is allowed to resign prior to a complaint being filed.

Is the officer still protected under qualified immunity if they are not police officers when the complaint is filed?

Comment: Just because the police person has resigned does not mean you cannot sue. If you have formal admittance of guilt then that is massive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

What’s relevant is if they were a police officer at the time the violation occurred.

Comment: Qualified immunity is not some sort of get out of jail free card.

Comment: @NeilMeyer I never suggested it was. However, QI applies to the situation in the OP.